# Angular TypeScript : can't assign array to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, typescript

So in this component, i am getting an array of objects from api "adherents", which is working fine and i use to display a table but when i create a new array "temp_adherents", and assign the first array to it and try to work with it, it's empty, and in the console, i get an error that the new array is undefined, here's my code:

```
export class AdherentsComponent implements OnInit {
  adherents: adherent[];

  constructor(private adherentService: AdherentService, private alertify: AlertifyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAdherents();
  }

  temp_adherents = this.adherents // this is where the problem is

  getAdherents() {
    this.adherentService.getAdherents().subscribe((
      adherents: adherent[]) => {
      this.adherents = adherents;
    }, error => { this.alertify.error(error); })
  }


}
```

Comment: That line is outside any functions; what's it supposed to be doing anyway?

Comment: i think u have to define the new array as let  temp_adherents: string[] (it it's string values)

Comment: `this.adherents` isn't assigned a value until `subscribe` `this.adherentService.getAdherents()` completes and calls your `subscribe` callback. Before that, it is `undefined`. What are you trying to accomplish? @Harish, it has nothing to do with the types.